# How to check the time constantly on a running Node.js app

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am currently working with Twilio and it has been awesome but I have been wondering how you can constantly check time for a Node app when it is running on heroku so that if you hit a certain time, you get a text message.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: tytytytytytytyty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku and node-cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057883/heroku-and-node-cron)