# Issue while sending messages on WhatsApp at specific time everyday using Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, server, cron, whatsapp

I'm writing a program in Node.js which sends a WhatsApp template every day at a specific time. I used node-cron and setInterval. When I deployed the program on https://dashboard.render.com/# or https://id.heroku.com/login to run it remotely it doesn't work. but when I run it locally on VSCode it works fine, I can't seem to figure out the issue.

Help is appreciated.

```
const express = require('express');
const webApp = express();

webApp.use(express.json());
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
function myFunc() {
    // console.log("Checking every 2 second")
    cron.schedule('15 16 * * *', () => {
        console.log("Checking every 2 second")
        sendDayTemplate();

    })
}
setTimeout(myFunc, 1000);

webApp.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running at ${PORT}`);
});
```

[Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uabk7.png)
[Render logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgUlR.png)

Comment: Do you have error logs from heroku.? You can find by following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging
Also heroku servers are shut if here is no traffic. That could be reason.

Comment: Yes, I have attached the logs in the edited question. Is there a way I can keep the server running?

Comment: This could be of help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057883/heroku-and-node-cron

Comment: One of the answers suggested to keep the pinging the server, is that good practice? if yes, any suggested method I should implement? Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I believe using heroku scheduler will be better option than ping system